# Why the GUI does not appear after converting py to exe?

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, qt-designer

I have created GUI using QtDesigner and python. The GUI contains two windows- the second window is connected to the first one in this way:

```
class Ui_First(object):

    def openWindow(self):

        self.window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui=Ui_Second()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        First.close()
        self.window.show()
```

and is opened by Next button.

I try to convert my py files into exe. I use this command in windows command line:

```
pyinstaller -y  --add-data "C:/Users/pukma/Desktop/toExe/back.py";"."  "C:/Users/pukma/Desktop/toExe/GUI.py" -F
```

I obtain the exe file but the Gui isn't work. A black python window is appeared, which disappears after a while and the interface does not appear.

Comment: first I tried auto-py-to-exe and the pyinstaller line is from this module

Comment: execute `pyinstaller --windowed C:/Users/pukma/Desktop/toExe/GUI.py`

Comment: It also doesn't work.

Comment: Saying that it doesn't work is not good feedback if you expect help, you should give more information such as: do you get any error message, etc? On the other hand I recommend you provide a [mre], you could also use fbs https://pypi.org/project/fbs/

Comment: the error message is : Failed to execute script GUI

Comment: It is probably another mistake so it reinforces my idea that you provide an MRE, you may also need a .dll and to know it you can use dependency walker. Also, the version of pyinstaller, python, etc. may not be adequate. You realize that you need to provide more information if you want help.

Comment: The interface works fine if it is run from a python script. I am using  python 3.7 and pyinstaller 3.5

Comment: @Gosia ***"Failed to execute script GUI "***: Use `pyinstaller ...` **without** the parameter `--windowed` and run it from a Windows `command prompt` to see the culprit of the error message.

Comment: The error message is : ImportError: unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH

Comment: But the Qt5Core.dll is in the directory where my exe file is.

Comment: @Gosia ***"where my exe file is"***: The `dll` have to be in the `PATH`. Pick one of [`[python] [pyinstaller] pyqt5 Qt5Core.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+%5Bpyinstaller%5D+pyqt5+Qt5Core.dll)